# MySQL enable query logging without restart

Tags: mysql

I want to track all MySQL queries without service restart. I know that i can enable the slow_queries log without restarting

`root in [~]# touch /var/log/slow
root in [~]# chown mysql:mysql /var/log/slow
root in [~]# mysql -e 'SET GLOBAL slow_query_log=1;'
root in [~]# mysql -e 'SET GLOBAL slow_query_log_file="/var/log/slow";'`

Is it possible to set the slow_query time too low in order to track all the queries of the server ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not must enable the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html)? `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to set the slow_query time too low in order to track all the queries of the server ?

If you meant the `long_query_time`, [yes it is](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time):

> Dynamic Variable: Yes
>   Min Value: 0

But if you want to log *all* queries, the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html) is indeed more appropriate (and it can be started and stopped without restarting too).